# Why does the compiler keep asking me to declare internal functions?

Tags: solidity, erc-20, erc-223

I am using this ERC223 compliant code to accept an ERC20 token as payment (provided by @aviral agrawal). Why does the compiler keep asking me to declare the **balances** function? I thought it was an built-in function? It did this for the **balanceOf** and **safeSub** functions as well.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.2;

contract getLaundri{

function balanceOf( address who ) constant returns (uint balances) {
  return balances[who];
}

function transferToContract(address _to, uint _value, bytes _data) private returns (bool success) {

require(balanceOf(msg.sender) >= _value);
balances[msg.sender] = safeSub(balanceOf(msg.sender), _value);
balances[_to] = safeAdd(balanceOf(_to), _value);
ContractReceiver reciever = ContractReceiver(_to);
reciever.tokenFallback(msg.sender, _value, _data);
Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value, _data);
StateChanged(true,"Transfer to contract successful");
return true;


}

}
```

This is the error message:

```
 Undeclared identifier.
balances[msg.sender] = safeSub(balanceOf(msg.sender), _value);
^------^
```

Answer (score 1):

You never declared the property `balances` on your contract.  It's not built-in, it's a implementation detail of most token contracts.  If you look at some others, you'll see something like `mapping balances(address => uint256)` declared within the scope of the contract itself (not one of its functions).

Answer (score 0):

ERC20 and ERC223 are standards that provide a skeleton of what functionalities, variables and event your smart contract must have in order for it to be a standard token. These functions and variables are not in built and must be declared.

Declare the balances as a mapping as mentioned by @DeviateFish. Also include all the functionalities of ERC223 to make it a standard token

Thank you for the mention. It means a lot to me.

P.S.
Always use the latest version of solidity. Each release brings a whole lot of functionalities(As of writing [0.4.14](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/blob/develop/Changelog.md))